# OpenLayers3 Draw Interaction and click event issues

Tags: openlayers

I plotted a cluster layer within a proximity(polygon) using draw interaction.Clusters get plotted inside.

But when i tried to put click events on cluster layer using map.forEachFeatureAtPixel , click events don't give the feature attributes of clusters within the drawn proximity even after hiding and removing the drawn polygon layer.

When i checked the layer which is clicked using map.forEachFeatureAtPixel i found it is not the cluster layer.

Please Note: Click events on clusters work fine for all cluster layers outside the drawn polygon.

Can't upload the code,sorry.